# Indicator variable for dataframe in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe about the past test result of a group of students

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Student_ID': [1,2,1,1,2,3,1,3,3,3,2,2],
     'Date': ['2021-04-28','2022-05-21','2011-03-01','2021-11-28','1992-12-01','1999-10-28','2022-01-12','2019-02-28','2001-03-28','2022-01-01','2009-05-28','2002-07-22'],
     'Subject': ['algebra','geometry','geometry','geometry','calculus','calculus','geometry','calculus','calculus','algebra','algebra','geometry']
})
```

And I want to add a new column called `Advantage` which equals `1` if the student had taken the same subject in at least 2 of the past 3 recent tests and `0` otherwise. So the output looks like

```
    Student_ID  Date        Subject  Advantage
6    1          2022-01-12  geometry 1        
3    1          2021-11-28  geometry 0            
0    1          2021-04-28  algebra  0         
2    1          2011-03-01  geometry 0             
1    2          2022-05-21  geometry 0           
10   2          2009-05-28  algebra  0
11   2          2002-07-22  geometry 0           
4    2          1992-12-01  calculus 0           
9    3          2022-01-01  algebra  0           
7    3          2019-02-28  calculus 1           
8    3          2001-03-28  calculus 0
5    3          1999-10-28  calculus 0
```

Here's what I have tried: first I sorted the dataframe by time:

```
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df.sort_values(by=['Student_ID', 'Date'], ascending = [True, False], inplace=True)
```

And then I think it might help to use the `np.where` or `np.select` function but I am stuck. Thank you in advance.

Edit:
Here is a longer version of the example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Student_ID': [1,2,1,1,2,3,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2],
     'Date': ['2021-04-28','2022-05-21','2011-03-01','2021-11-28','1992-12-01','1999-10-28','2022-01-12','2019-02-28','2001-03-28','2022-01-01','2009-05-28','2002-07-22', '2005-7-01', '2004-7-22', '2012-03-22', '2009-10-12'],
     'Subject': ['algebra','geometry','geometry','geometry','calculus','calculus','geometry','calculus','calculus','algebra','algebra','geometry', 'calculus', 'calculus', 'geometry', 'geometry'],
     'Advantage':  [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
})

df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], dayfirst=True)
df.sort_values(by=['Student_ID', 'Date'], ascending = [True, False], inplace=True)
df
```

and the desired output looks like:

```
Student_ID  Date    Subject Advantage
6   1   2022-01-12  geometry    1
3   1   2021-11-28  geometry    0
0   1   2021-04-28  algebra     0
2   1   2011-03-01  geometry    0
1   2   2022-05-21  geometry    1
14  2   2012-03-22  geometry    0
15  2   2009-10-12  geometry    0
10  2   2009-05-28  algebra     0
12  2   2005-07-01  calculus    1
13  2   2004-07-22  calculus    0
11  2   2002-07-22  geometry    0
4   2   1992-12-01  calculus    0
9   3   2022-01-01  algebra     0
7   3   2019-02-28  calculus    1
8   3   2001-03-28  calculus    0
5   3   1999-10-28  calculus    0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
# Import Data
df = pd.DataFrame({
     'Student_ID': [1,2,1,1,2,3,1,3,3,3,2,2,2,2,2,2],
     'Date': ['2021-04-28','2022-05-21','2011-03-01','2021-11-28','1992-12-01','1999-10-28','2022-01-12','2019-02-28','2001-03-28','2022-01-01','2009-05-28','2002-07-22', '2005-7-01', '2004-7-22', '2012-03-22', '2009-10-12'],
     'Subject': ['algebra','geometry','geometry','geometry','calculus','calculus','geometry','calculus','calculus','algebra','algebra','geometry', 'calculus', 'calculus', 'geometry', 'geometry'],
    #  'Advantage':  [1,1,0,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,0,0]
})

df.sort_values(['Student_ID','Date'],ascending=[True,False] ,inplace=True)
df.reset_index(inplace=True)
df['Index_Link']=df.reset_index().index

# Create Groups for Different Groups
df['Group'] = (df[['Student_ID', 'Subject']] != df[['Student_ID', 'Subject']].shift()).any(axis=1)
df['Group'] = df['Group'].cumsum()

# df['Group'].value_counts()
df_required = pd.DataFrame(df['Group'].value_counts())
df_required_lkp =  df_required.loc[df_required['Group'] >=2].reset_index()
df_required_v1 = pd.merge(df,df_required_lkp[['index','Group']], how='inner',left_on='Group', right_on='index')
df_required_v2 = df_required_v1.groupby(['Student_ID','Group_x']).first().reset_index()
df_required_v2['Advantage_Final'] = 1
# df_required_v2

df_final = pd.merge(df,df_required_v2[['Index_Link','Advantage_Final']], how='left',left_on='Index_Link', right_on='Index_Link')
df_final['Advantage_Final'] = df_final['Advantage_Final'].fillna(0)
df_final.drop(['index','Group','Index_Link'],axis=1,inplace=True)
df_final.rename(columns={"Advantage_Final":"Advantage"},inplace=True)

# Output Showing
df_final
```

Hi Nayr,

I think this is what you want (Without Loop)

If you have any question please let me know

Thanks
Leon

Comment: Hi @yuehengli thank you for your help but I think this isn't exactly what I want because I want the column to output one if it's the same subject for at least 2 of the past 3 recent tests, but it seems that the column now outputs one if it's the same subject for at 2 tests in the past (not just past 3 recent test) due to ```cumcount```.

Comment: Dear Leon, I just made an edit in my question because the comment section won't allow me to write too long. I just ran the above code but it seems it's still not working, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Hi Nayr, from your new example :0   Student_ID = 1   date = 2021-04-28  subject = algebra     advantage = 1, why this record has advantage = 1? he only took  algebra for one time?

Comment: Hi Leon, sorry I just updated it, it should be 0, sorry for the confusion.

Comment: To clarify, I want the advantage to be equal to 1 if for the past 3 tests the student took, at least 2 of them are the same as the subject the student is taking this time and zero otherwise. Thank you so much for your help:)

Comment: Hi Nayr, Now I am clear what you want, give me a little bit time to adjust code  Thanks Leon

Comment: Hi yuehengli, appreciated for your help and the code works now but I would like to ask is there any way to avoid the use of a for loop? Because my actual dataframe is much larger and it is very computationally expensive to run a for loop. I wonder is there a more computationally economic way to do this, thank you so much.

Comment: Hi Nayr, I thought you are doing analysis under small sample, I will provide you another code for Larger Dataset, please provide me sometime to adjust the code Thanks Leon

Comment: Hi yuehengli, sorry I should have said it's a huge dataset with about 300,000 rows. Thank you so much for your help, really appreciated.

Comment: Hi Nayr, I have edit the code I have attached above, it will be better for your large dataset now, if you have any question please let me know thanks leon

Comment: yuehengli thank you so much for your help, really appreciated!:)

Comment: It's Great to help you with it. See you next time Nayr. Leon